# Expand div from center

Tags: javascript, html, css, center, expand

I'm trying to make a circle div expandable like google material design but something does not work.
I want it to expand and fill the page (from top 0 and right 0) and stay in position. But when width and height increase, the center of div moves.

I want the same effect on search button on this template (ThemeForest): https://html.nkdev.info/_con/dashboard.html

Here my code :

```js
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
  $('.to-expand').css({
    'width': '300px',
    'height': '300px'
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.to-expand {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="expand">expand</a>
<div class="to-expand"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking from scale:

```js
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
  $('.to-expand').addClass('scale');
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.to-expand {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.scale {
  transform:scale(15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="expand">expand</a>
<div class="to-expand"></div>
```

Comment: I tried but top fill the page some aliazing apear on my div :(
Thanks for your answer ! :)

Comment: @Lucas so you can start with scale and get back to 1 ;)

Comment: There is always `will-change: transform` too

Comment: Yes but if i want to fill the page and star from 1px width and height. My scale will be more than 300.. How can i do to dismiss the aliazing ? :(

Comment: @Lucas you make the element 300px at the start and you apply a scale to make it small, then you apply scale(1) to make it bigger :)

Comment: Oh ok i will try this if there is not aliazing

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: scale(15)` instead of manipulating `width` and `height`.

```js
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
  $('.to-expand').css({
    "transform": "scale(15)"
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.to-expand {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="expand">expand</a>
<div class="to-expand"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
  $('.to-expand').addClass('expanded');
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.to-expand {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.expanded{
  top: -100vmax;
  right: -100vmax;
  width: 250vmax;
  height: 250vmax;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<a class="expand">expand</a>
<div class="to-expand"></div>
```

Comment: Yes but it's not proportional :/ I'm looking for a perfect circle :( Thank you

Comment: @Lucas oh, there, i've changed the class, and now is a perfect circle that covers the entire screen